# Renaming files in a folder while keeping extension unchanged

Tags: excel, vba

I have file names in Column A to be changed to the values in Column B. The extension shouldn't change while renaming.

```
Sub rename
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim OldFile As String
    Dim NewFile As String
    Set Source = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    For Row = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
        OldFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
        NewFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2)
        ' rename files
        Name OldFile As Newfile
    Next
end sub
```

Comment: And you couldn't find anything on SO or internet to help you with this??

Comment: @nightcrawler23 if you find then paste the code.

Comment: Googling `excel vba rename files in folder` gives 141,000 results - did none of those work?

Comment: @YowE3K simply say you don't know, rather than wasting time in commenting

Comment: OP, we suggest you read and follow [advice/rules of how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One of the first steps is to [Search SO for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search). Look at [one of possible searches](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+rename+files)

Comment: @YowE3K  I googled it before posting my question. The problem that I'm facing is different. Suppose file name previously was a1.jpg and after running the macro it is only a1. So i'm unable to open that file directly. That shouldn't happen. Now if you understood the problem then help.

Comment: In that case you should post your code here and get help to solve your specific problem instead of asking to give you a complete solution

Comment: "after running the macro it is only a1" - If you have code that isn't working, post it, with an explanation of what is not working, and we can work to fix it.

Comment: @BranislavKollár it's better read my problem first and all the comments. The problem is totally different.

Comment: sub rename
 Dim Source As Range
 Dim OldFile As String
 Dim NewFile As String

 Set Source = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

 For Row = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
    OldFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    NewFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2)

    ' rename files
    Name OldFile As Newfile

 Next
 end sub




This is the code.  The problem that I'm facing is different. Suppose file name previously was a1.jpg and after running the macro it is only a1. So i'm unable to open that file directly. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: @nightcrawler23 check above code

Comment: @YowE3K check above code

Comment: Do you need to handle extensions longer than, say, 5 characters?

Comment: @YowE3K extensions are like jpg, jpeg, xlsx, xls... It varies.. It can be 3,4,5.

Comment: suppose you post a shot of your columns A and B with actual names you're dealing with, we could help you more effectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification to your code will strip off any extensions from `NewFile` (providing the extension is no longer than 5 characters long):

```
Sub Rename()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim OldFile As String
    Dim NewFile As String
    Dim Row As Long
    Set Source = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    For Row = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
        OldFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
        NewFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2)
        'see if NewFile contains an extension
        If InStr(Right(NewFile, 6), ".") > 0 Then
            'if so, strip it off
            NewFile = Left(NewFile, InStrRev(NewFile, ".") - 1)
        End If
        'append extension
        NewFile = NewFile & Mid(OldFile, InStrRev(OldFile, "."))
        ' rename files
        Name OldFile As NewFile
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: its not working. when i am renaming asde.jpg to a1.jpg, then it's renaming as a1de.jpg

Comment: @matangraj - Sorry, `Right` should have been `Mid`, but I would have expected that to be creating `a1e.jpg`, not `a1de.jpg`

Comment: so which line need to be changed?

Comment: @matangraj, how many occurrences of `Right` do you see in the code YowE3k kindly gave you?

Comment: @user3598756 my mistake..sorry

Comment: @YowE3K 1 thing I want to ask, In this whole code, I'm not specifying  which folder to select? So how does macro knows I'm referring to that folder only? Any suggestions

Comment: @user3598756 1 thing I want to ask, In this whole code, I'm not specifying  which folder to select? So how does macro knows I'm referring to that folder only? Any suggestions

Comment: @matangraj - it would be working because you have the path as part of the filenames, or the files are in the `CurDir`.  And, if you ask "how do I change the `CurDir`?", I am going to say "GOOGLE IT!!".  (`excel vba curdir command`)

Comment: @YowE3K Suppose I want to know the file names from the folder in column A and then replace from the values that I give in column B. What should be the procedure

Comment: @matangraj - that question I don't even understand - and I am about to go to bed (it's 7:30pm, and I get up at 2:30am), so I won't have a chance to think about this any more until tomorrow.

Comment: @YowE3K Ok No issues. Thanks

Comment: @YowE3K I got the macro for this also..thanks by the way